# New to Python, i need to make this loop? i know its's really cluttered

Tags: python

How can I make this loop, and if possible is there anyway I can tidy it up?

```
l,a,b, = 0, 0, 0
password = str(input("Please enter a strong, 12 character password: "))
for i in password:
 if password[0] or [1] or [2] or [3] or [4] or [5] or [6] or [7] or [8] or [9] or [10] or [11] or 
[12].islower():
  l+=1
if password[0] or [1] or [2] or [3] or [4] or [5] or [6] or [7] or [8] or [9] or [10] or [11] or 
[12].isupper():
a+=1
if len(password) == 12:
b+=1
if l>=1 and a>=1 and b>=1:
print("valid password")
else:
print("invalid password")
```

Comment: Note that your code absolutely does not do what you expect. `[1]` is just a single-element list of an integer, for example. Hence the `AttributeError` you're presumably asking about (although you don't mention it).

Comment: How about you describe what you're trying to do, because whatever it is, this code does not do it.

Comment: You need to do something like `any(map(password, lambda x: x.islower()))` instead.

Comment: @khelwood, I agree

Comment: What would be the expected input criteria? Contains a 12 long array of both lower and upper characters of the alphabet of your choice?

Comment: If you gonna write a password strength checker, there's a better way.

Comment: "Make this loop" does not tell us what you want to do.  We expect you to use existing tutorials and other materials before posting here -- you need to learn how to write a compound Boolean expression, and you need to research existing password checkers.  You have several errors in your code; please clean it up to where you're asking about only *one* problem.

Comment: ` password[0] or [1] or [2] or [3] or [4] or [5] or [6] or [7] or [8] or [9] or [10] or [11] or 
[12].isupper():` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: @prune  the code runs fine, there are no errors, it is a password  checker, but if the password is invalid i want it to loop the question again.

Comment: @khelwood  the code runs fine, there are no errors, it is a password  checker, but if the password is invalid i want it to loop the question again

Comment: The code you have posted does not run fine. It has multiple errors. Even if you fixed the indentation so it can be run, it still would not do what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @khelwood, works fine for me idk why its not for you,  some one has posted an answer anyway so thank you

Comment: @mr_freddy if the provided answer works, it would be nice to mark as accepted.

Comment: @nagyl sorry, im  new to thi, how can i mark as accepted??

Comment: In that case, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: @mr_freddy It did not work fine for you. You just didn't test it very thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

1. Cleaner code:

```
l, a, b, = 0, 0, 0
password = str(input("Please enter a strong, 12 character password: "))
for i in password:
    if i.islower():
        l += 1
    if i.isupper():
        a += 1
if len(password) == 12:
    b += 1
if l >= 1 and a >= 1 and b >= 1:
    print("valid password")
else:
    print("invalid password")
```

2. What about non-letter characters like ":"?

Comment: this looks much better, thank you so much!

Comment: You also have to care about the non-letter characters.